# Change Windows 10 Calendar Scrollwheel Settings

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, calendar, scrolling, scroll-wheel

I used to use the old Windows 7 system tray calendar on Windows 10, but that functionality has been disabled by recent updates.

My main gripe with the Windows 10 calendar is that the scroll wheel goes week by week instead of month by month as it did in the old Windows 7 calendar. Is there any way to change this? The color scheme makes it too hard to quickly decipher which month I'm actually looking at when it goes week by week.

Comment: See the mouse control panel. You can certainly make it scroll a lot by choosing screen at a time. If you go to the real mouse applet (type `main.cpl` in Run Winkey+R) and change the lines to scroll. This is system wide.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling in the Windows calendar from the Start menu is really bad and not customizable.

Clicking on the date in the traybar (down right) will open a simpler interface that
scrolls month-by-month, but doesn't display much information.

You might get better interface from a more evolved third-party calendar product
such as the free [EssentialPIM](https://www.essentialpim.com/).

Comment: I only use the calendar in the system tray. I will look into the Essential PIM product, but my main goal is to have a calendar in the system tray I can quickly reference and scroll through month-by-month just so I can see dates.